# Jquery ui dialog is loading multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am just working on jquery-ui dialog box, i triggered it with small image icon. So when we click on it, dialog box appears. I am using dialog box for so many questions around 100.

This seems to work fine but when I use it in my code i get the dialog box content text came without a title and dialog box with a title only are coming particularly. I think it is due to click event is triggered multiple times.

**HTML code:**

```
<img class="A" src="pics/hello.png" id="title">
<span id="dialog_text" class="D" title="dialogBox">
   I am a dialog box
</span>
```

**JS:**

```
function dialogBox(open, dial){
  if(dial.length>0 && open.length>0){
    dial.dialog({ 
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 300,
      height: "auto",
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Close: function() {
          dial.dialog( "close" );
        }  
      }
    });

    open.click(function() {
      dial.dialog("open");
      return false;
    });    
  }

  dial.css("font-size", "18px");

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var dialoge = $("#dialog_text");
  if (dialoge){     
    var head = $("#title");
    head.click(dialogBox(head, dialoge));

  }
});
```

Here when i click on image i got two dialog boxes, one without title and dialog text and other with title and without dialog text.
Thanks

Comment: try `dialoge.on("click",dialogBox(head, dialoge))`

Comment: nope bro, same problem remains.

Comment: can i see a codepen ?

Comment: In codepen, it will work. When we come on a page first time or new page, then it shows the error but after reloading there is no error.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated , @SupunPraneeth try this code on multiple pages site. then check.

Comment: do you have multiple `#dialog_text` tags?

Comment: yes, but their id is different

Comment: this works fine, if it's hard to say when i don't have a full code

Answer (score 0):

Try doing all the logic inside click events. Much simpler imo.

```
$("#dialog_text").click(function() {
  $(this).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 300,
    height: "auto",
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      close: function() {
        $(this).dialog( "close" );
      }  
    },
  }).css("font-size", "18px");
});

$('#title').click(function() {
  $('#dialog_text').dialog('open');
});
```